# Генерация изображения по другому изображению

Tags: python

Алгоритм реализации таков:
Берётся изображение, как ниже, с одним цветом и альфа-каналом. Код считывает ширину и высоту заданного изображения. После чего создаёт ещё одно изображение с такой же шириной и высотой, допустим, в один пиксель
Затем код возвращается к первому изображению и начинает обрабатывать его попиксельно по столбцам сверху вниз. Если на первом изображении в столбце только альфа-канал, то на втором изображении код генерирует чёрный пикселью. Если в столбце при сканировании сверху вниз при высоте в 100 пикселей на 60 альфа-канал прервётся, то на втором изображении генерируется пиксель с цветовым тоном близко к серому. Если в столбце на первом изображении при сканировании сверху вниз в принципе нет альфа-канала, то на втором генерируется пиксель белого цвета, и так далее
На чём и как это можно реализовать? По возможности с примером
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чём вопрос? Или это тех. задание?

Comment: Вопрос в том, на чём и как это можно реализовать, и по возможности с примером

Comment: Ну, `OpenCV`, наверное. Да или просто загрузить хоть в чём картинку, преобразовать в `Numpy` массив, а дальше реализовывать алгоритм.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну да, или `Pillow`, тут не так много вариантов в общем-то.